Wiring a 6-30r and a 6-15r on a 30 amp circuit
Can I have a 6-30r and a 6-15r on the same circuit using a 30 amp breaker and  10awg-2 wire?

Wow, which country are you in?

Quite sure 6-15 cannot be on a 30 amp breaker, unless protected by a 15 amp breaker/fuse

In the USA,
NEC 210.21(B)(3) requires a 15-Amp or 20-Amp circuit breaker where "two or more" outlets are on the circuit with a receptacle rating of 15 Amp.  For a 30-Amp circuit, it requires receptacles with a 30-Amp rating.  Mixing 15-Amp and 30-Amp outlets is not allowed on any circuit.  This paragraph says, "receptacle ratings shall conform to the values listed".
In 2023, this was clarified to say, "receptacle rating shall not be less than the values listed."  Under this code, all receptacles on the 30-Amp circuit would have to be rated 30-Amp or more.
Both codes provide exceptions for arc welders and discharge lighting.
